# Tensorflow 2.1 gives different neural net convergence on windows vs linux for Python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorflow2.0

Machine 1 :
LAMBDA QUAD LINUX Ubuntu:18.04 
Deep Learning Workstation with 4 GPUs
[convergence of neural net model on lambda ( Linux)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1311P.png)
Machine 2 : 
Lenovo Thinkpad T480 Intel Windows 10. 
[convergence of neural net model on ThinkPad (Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yibFi.png)

Both machines are running exactly the same piece of code, exactly the same dataset, both have Python 3.6 and tensorflow 2.1. However, I found a difference in package versions on both machines. But that does not explain the early stopping on a windows machine around 2000 iterations whereas on the Linux the network seems to have not been trained even after 5000 iterations.

Comment: What package difference are you talking about?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal: So when we install TF2.1 on both the machines, there are many other packages that gets installed as dependencies. that's what i mean by package versions on both machines to have a difference..  i don't think that should cause that big of a difference as one model has early stopped around 2000 and the other one doesn't even converge after 5000 iterations.